# SQL - error when using UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

Here's my query:

```
Select top 1 ProductName, UnitPrice from Products
order by UnitPrice desc

UNION

Select top 1 ProductName, UnitPrice from Products
Where UnitPrice > 0
order by UnitPrice asc
```

I wanted to display the most expensive and the cheapest products in one table. That's why I used UNION to join the two queries. Unfortunately I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'

That's why I'm asking for your help - what's wrong with my query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551064/combining-order-by-and-union-in-sql-server duplicate.  Cannot combine order by with union but using multple ctes, subqueries, or cte with window functions can get you the answer. Also curious what if 2 products have the exact same expensive or cheap price would you want more than 1 result?

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question. If most expensive had the same price as the cheapest I would like to see both results

Comment: no worries some times it is hard to figure out terminology to search for.  My question of 2 products is actually slightly different than your eample lets say you have 2 products that have the same cheap price and 2 different products that have the same expensive price do you want all 4 products or just 1 of each?  Because if you want all 4 products you need to my answer with the window functions below. not the other methods.

Comment: That's good to know. I think I could also use WITH TIES in order to display all products with the same prices. Actually, I'll try to see it that would work

Comment: good point I don't use with ties but you could do that too

Comment: I just tried that and it worked. Again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH X AS 
  (
    Select top 1 ProductName, UnitPrice from Products
    order by UnitPrice desc
  ), 
 Y AS 
  (
    Select top 1 ProductName, UnitPrice from Products
    Where UnitPrice > 0
    order by UnitPrice asc 
)
SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice FROM X
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice FROM Y
```

Comment: Good answer. It's also a good idea to add WITH TIES to be able to see if there are more products with the same price (for example 2 cheapes products)

Answer (score 2):

As Sub Select

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT *
       ,MinPriceRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_Dt)
       ,MaxPriceRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_Dt DESC)
       ,MinPriceRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Start_Dt)
       ,MaxPriceRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Start_Dt DESC)
    FROM    
       #Table
    ) t
WHERE
    MinPriceRowNum = 1
    OR MaxPriceRowNum = 1
```

AS Common Table Expression cte

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
       ,MinPriceRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UnitPrice)
       ,MaxPriceRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UnitPriceDESC)
       ,MinPriceRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UnitPrice)
       ,MaxPriceRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UnitPriceDESC)
    FROM    
       TableName
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    MinPriceRowNum = 1
    OR MaxPriceRowNum = 1
```

If you want to see all ties for max and min switch to `MinPriceRank = 1 OR MaxPriceRank = 1`.  If only 1 row desired stay with the RowNum columns.

Comment: Your answer is good, but I checked the other one as correct answer, because the syntax you used is more complicated and, to be honest, I don't fully understand it. I only know the basics of SQL. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I was using window functions and common table expressions.  Both will be assets for you to put in your sql toolbox

Comment: Unfortunately I just finished my SQL course at university, but I hope I'll have an opportunity to learn some more, because it seems to be more interesting than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use round brackets like this:

```
(Select top 1 ProductName, UnitPrice from Products order by UnitPrice desc)
UNION
(Select top 1 ProductName, UnitPrice from Products Where UnitPrice > 0 order by UnitPrice asc)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but thanks for trying to help