# Insert with select for multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, union

I have an insert statements for which I want to make 2 inserts. I have the following code:

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Licemb]
        ([Lic_Id],
        [LicEmb_EmbTS],
        [LicEmb_EmbOffset])

            SELECT TOP 1 
            Lic_ID,
            '00:00:00',
            -7 
            FROM dbo.Lics
            WHERE Org_ID = 2
            ORDER BY NP_ID DESC

            UNION ALL

            SELECT TOP 1 
            Lic_ID,
            '00:00:00',
            -7 
            FROM dbo.Lics
            WHERE Org_ID = 4
            ORDER BY NP_ID DESC
```

however I keep getting syntax errors and I can't find a work around after searching for a while.

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
```

How can I modify this code so that I can use a single statement to make 2 inserts with selects?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code contains product specific functionality.

Comment: yes, I have added INSERT INTO [dbName].[dbo].[Licemb] but still errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can only have one order by for your entire union statement.

if you need to order each select you will need to run a sub query and union them

so

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Licemb]
            ([Lic_Id],
            [LicEmb_EmbTS],
            [LicEmb_EmbOffset])

            select id,daytime,embargo from (
            SELECT TOP 1 
            Lic_ID      AS id,
            '00:00:00'  AS daytime,
            -7          AS embargo
            FROM [NLASQL].dbo.Lics
            WHERE Org_ID = 2
            ORDER BY NP_ID DESC) 

            UNION ALL

            select id,daytime,embargo from (
            SELECT TOP 1 
            Lic_ID      AS id,
            '00:00:00'  AS daytime,
            -7          AS embargo
            FROM [NLASQL].dbo.Lics
            WHERE Org_ID = 4
            ORDER BY NP_ID DESC)
```

this is not an ideal solution and would ask why you need to order each set of data and then approach the problem from that angle.

Comment: sql server doesn't allow `order by` in a sub query.

Comment: only if top is not specfied

Comment: Very true, only just noticed that bit. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: not a problem I had to do a double take myself as well.

Comment: I've added my changes above and I get the following errors:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Comment: we don't have a `set` anywhere in the code provided. my assumption would be this is only a fraction of the code you have. with that said we would be unable to determine what is and isn't missing if we do not have a complete sample of the code.  are you using a `set` in your script anywhere else?

Comment: ok i've anded the code in this answer. This solution works. Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `union (all)`, there can only be one `order by`, namely after the last unioned query. This `order by` is applied over all queries in the `union`.

Comment: ok but I need the order by for each select, what do I do then?

Comment: In the query you posted you have the same `order by` for both queries, so there is no issue. If you want query 1 to be sorted in a different way than query2, you'll have to think of something clever. For example, you could `select 1 as selection` and `select 2 as selection` for the respective queries. And than `order by selection`. It all depends on how you want thing sorted.

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551064/combining-order-by-and-union-in-sql-server. You put select quieries in subqueries

Comment: A bit late, but I only just noticed you use `top 1` as well, in that case you *can* use subqueries with `order by`